# how to disable scaling of a text field?

Tags: html, forms, textfield, disable

I have a message field with a corner for which the user can drag to enlarge/shrink the field. I want to disable that, because the user would just mess up with how the form looks like on my website if they would scale it in a random size.

Not sure if I could find any answer to this with just Google search results alone.

```
<div class="col-12">

<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" autocomplete="off" rows="6"></textarea>

</div>
```

Does anyone know the html code to turn off the scaling of this text input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing can be disabled using CSS `resize: none`

```
<textarea style="resize: none" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" autocomplete="off" rows="6"></textarea>
```